# tensorflow multiple device training terms

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to launch my deep network on multiple devices. I'm using the slim framework provided in `tensorflow/models/slim`. But I have difficulty in understanding the terms in the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py).

What are the meanings of `clone`, `replica`, `parameter-server(ps)` and `worker`? Can anyone explain them to a real system muggle like me?